# XT derailleur 1995 maximum teeth?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear

I'm trying to upgrade my cassette for lower gearing on a Nishiki Continental. The previous owner put on a (NOS) Shimano XT rear derailleur. I use friction shifters.

I looked on the back of the cage and the models says RD-M739. The document from Shimano says 32T maximum. What do you think, would a 34T 9-speed work?

I would like to have a bigger rear cog so I'm asking just to be sure it's not a RD-M739-SGS. How can I tell? Would SGS be stamped on the back if it would be?

Thanks!

[image: RD-M739 front]
[image: RD-M739 back]

Update: I actually found a 7sp overdrive with a 34T largest cog on another bike that I tried. Seems to work just as fine as on the bike it came from.

[image: Overdrive 34T with the XT RD]

Comment: Offtopic, but the chain on the first photo looks incorrectly routed through RD cage.

Comment: Yes. It was when i got it (and took the pic). It's fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just mounted the 34t cassette and it works fine.

I also tried it on an even [older but same length DX derailleur](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54835/dx-derailleur-1990-maximum-teeth) and it worked there as well. Only using it for road and not MTB. Not sure if that makes any difference.